# Laravel created_at formatting

Tags: laravel

I am working in a laravel site and i just wanted to know if there was a way to format the created_at value for the users as now it is something along the lines of:

```
2017-09-20 13:41
```

But I would prefer to format it into an easily readable format such as

```
20th September 2017 13:41 (or 01:41pm if possible)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel's dates are Carbon objects, which have [a wide variety of built-in formats available](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats) as well as the ability to build [your own custom format](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) with the `format()` function.

So:

```
$foo->created_at->format('jS F Y h:i:s A')
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have been searching for ages

Comment: Would it work something like this then: {{$users->created_at->format('jS F Y h:i:s A')}} where $users is already requested and defined in web.php in the routes folder :)

Comment: That depends on what `$users` contains. If it's a single instance of a User model, then yes, it'll work fine.

Comment: Okay, I shall check tomorrow when I'm back at my desk! Thanks ceejayoz

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement the same in JS?

Comment: @SapneshNaik Implement what? Date formatting? Google "javascript date formatting".

Comment: @ceejayoz yeah. I managed to build up a function from different sources. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which version of Laravel you're using, but if it's 5+ you can specify the date format in your model.  This will affect the created_at, updated_at, and deleted_at (if using soft deletes) attributes.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

In database is not posible, but in php yes
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/